# Appearance of Forms I never created in Google Drive

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I have some Google Sheets file which I copy and change monthly. I never used Forms, but they are appearing all the time in the Drive and are related to this G.Sheets file as you can see on the screenshot -

[image]

Could you please explain why does it happen? How can I stop this behaviour? How can I use this auto-creatiion (the goal)??

Answer (score 3):

This happens because your Google Sheets is linked to a Google Form. When you copy the sheet you also copy the form.

You can create a new (not a copy) Google Sheet and copy the content from your old Google Sheet to it. Copying this new sheet will not create a new form.

Please be more clear about the auto-creation feature you are talking about.